# Booting stuck at : "A start job is running for /dev/mapper/cryptswap1"

Tags: boot, dell, 19.04, xps

I'm using Ubuntu 19.04 on a Dell XPS 13 (9360) and Ubuntu booting gets stuck at the following step:

```
A start job is running for /dev/mapper/cryptswap1
```

[image: ubuntu boot]

I have to reboot 1 or 2 times before getting rid of it. But it keeps happening on the following boot.

The problem presumably started after updating the linux kernel from 5.0.0-16 to 5.0.0-17. So I thought it may be linked so I tried to reboot with previous kernel versions (5.0.0.0-* and even 4.15) but I still got the same problem.

Both fstab and crypttab are unmodifed since the first installation (2 years ago):
/etc/fstab

```
UUID=e15636da-994d-47db-a074-cfccedf6a740 /               ext4    noatime,errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=222E-0C93  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p4 during installation
#UUID=10aaab21-f2ae-4e25-8f0b-55f444620108 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

/etc/crypttab

```
cryptswap1 UUID=10aaab21-f2ae-4e25-8f0b-55f444620108 /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64
```

I'm out of ideas. Any thoughts about it ?

Comment: Having this same issue after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.02 in an HP EliteBook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is no longer happening since I upgraded from Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan) to 20.04.1 (Focal). I don't know which part of the upgrade fixed it but it clearly did.

Answer (score 1):

it worked for me

Step 1: Create new swap partition

Step 2: Open the /etc/crypttab file and change the UUID present in the file to the UUID of the new SWAP partition

Comment: This doesn't provide enough details to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Two stabs in the darks.

Could you try to modify the swap description in /etc/fstab to

```
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap defaults 0 0
```

and in /etc/cryptab to

```
cryptswap1 UUID=10aaab21-f2ae-4e25-8f0b-55f444620108 /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64,size=512
```

A list idea would be to refer to the swap volume by its path rather than by its UUID, resulting in something like

```
cryptswap1 /dev/mapper/whatever--vg0-whatever /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64
```

Please not that it will not be crypt /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 as this is the device name after being turn in an encrypted swap by dm-crypt.

Answer (score 0):

In **Ubuntu 20.04** I fixed this by following these steps:

##### Step 1: Creating a Swap File with more space:

```
sudo fallocate -l 4G /swapfile
```

#### Step 2: Enabling the Swap File

```
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

#### Step 3: Making the Swap File Permanent

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak
echo '/swapfile none swap sw 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
```

#### Step 4: Commenting on the old swap partition line in `/etc/crypttab` and `/etc/fstab`

On `/etc/crypttab` I comment this line:

```
# cryptswap1 /swapfile /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64
```

And in `/etc/fstab` I comment only this line:

```
# /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```